# How do I set permissions on a directory so that all files created there will be read/write/execute for everyone?

Tags: macos, permission

I have a cache directory in which several different programs owned by several different accounts create/read/write/delete etc new files and directories. I want everyone to have all the possible rights to all of these things in this directory and everything that is ever created in it in the future.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the directory or Command + I after clicking on it, there will pop up a window like this. [image]

Clink on the padlock in lower right corner and type your password. Now you can change permissions for this directory. If you want everyone to be able to read and write, click on the privilege provided to Everyone and there will appear a dropdown menu from which you can choose what permission to provide.
[image]

I hope that helped.

Answer (score -1):

> I want everyone to have all the possible rights to all of these things in this directory and everything that is ever created in it in the future.

No, you really, really don't want to do that. You are solving one problem and creating many more.

What you want is for each user/process to be able to read/write/delete their own files but not break other things. Fortunately you are not the first person to come across this issue and there are two perfect solutions:

1. use /var/tmp as the cache directory, as it does this already
2. set the sticky bit on your own cache folder: `chmod 1777 my/tmp/`

gets a bit more complicated if it's a network share, but OS X server has access control lists to help.